# Alert message not being displayed by duplicate function when user enters duplicated values

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've been racking my brains trying to understand why my duplicate function isn't working. If everything worked as it should be the user should get an alert message each time s/he inputs a value twice. I tried to use the forEach method but the console kept throwing errors. So I'm now using good old for loop. No alert message being displayed either but at least the console isn't throwing any error, which I think is a step in the right direction.

```js
var elUlList = document.getElementById("uList");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const elInput = document.getElementById("input");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");
const message = document.getElementById("message");
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
const elCounter = document.getElementById("counter");



function createListItems() {
  var inputValue = elInput.value;
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  var newText = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  newLi.appendChild(newText);
  elUlList.appendChild(newLi);
  var array = Array.from(elements);
  function findDuplicates() {
    var compare = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(!compare.includes(array[i].textContent)){
        compare.push(array[i].textContent)
      } else {
        alert("Value already entered")
      }
    }
  }


  if(inputValue === "") {
    message.innerHTML = "field can't be left empty"
  }
  inputValue = ""

  elCounter.innerHTML =+ elements.length;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", createListItems, false);

elInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    btn.click()
  }
})

elInput.addEventListener("mouseover", emptyField, false)

function emptyField() {
  this.value = "";
}

elUlList.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  var parent = target.parentNode;
  alert("are you sure you want to remove this item from the list")
  parent.removeChild(target)
  elCounter.innerHTML =+ elements.length;
});

elUlList.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var child = e.target;
  if(elements.length >= 1){
    var elCounter = document.getElementById("counter");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i] === child ? elements[i].classList.toggle("lineThrough"):null;
  }
}
})


var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US")

footer.innerHTML = date
console.log(date)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="message"class=""></div>
  <ul id="uList"></ul>
  <button id="btn" type="button" name="button">click here to add items</button><br>
  <input id="input" type="text" name="" value="">
  <div id="counter" class=""></div>
  <footer></footer>


    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not calling your `findDuplicates();` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `findDuplicates` being called anywhere.
Also you should prolly call `document.getElementsByTagName("li")` every time you enter `createListItems` or `findDuplicates` to reflect changes you made in html (added `li` tags).